# Swift implicit conversion of type

Tags: swift, swift2

Let's say I've declared `UIViewController` as a property in my class. In some cases we can implicitly assign UINavigationController to this property.

```
UIViewController *someNavigationController
```

In Objective-C I can simple assign

```
UIViewController *vc = self.someNavigationController;

if (vc)
{
 //then do something
}
```

As I understood in Swift I should do something like this if my `self.centerViewController` declared as `UIViewController`. Right

```
let nvc = self.centerViewController as! UINavigationController
```

Alos how can I check

```
if nvc != nil
```

It says that it can't be nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as! UINavigationController` means it's a forced downcast: it has been unwrapped, it's no longer an Optional, therefore it can't be nil anymore - and if it *were* nil (or not downcastable), it would have crashed the app.

You could use optional binding instead:

```
if let nvc = self.centerViewController as? UINavigationController {
  // here, nvc is not nil and is a UINavigationController, you can use it
} else {
  // here, either self.centerViewController is nil or we can't cast it as a UINavigationController
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also check like this:-

```
if self.centerViewController is UINavigationController 
{
 // here self.centerViewController must be an instance of UINavigationController and not nil
  let nvc = self.centerViewController as! UINavigationController
} 
else {
      // here May be nil or may be an instance is of an other class
}
```